# C++ linker order of library with cyclic dependency

Tags: linker, g++, cyclic-dependency

I have two classes One and Two present in two individual cpp files. The contents are as follows

```
#include "One.h"
#include "Two.h"
namespace Sample 
{
  One::One() {}
  void One::foo1() {   
    Two t;
    t.foo();
  }   
  void One::foo()     {     }   
}
```

and Two.cpp is

```
#include "Two.h"
#include "One.h"
namespace Sample {
Two::Two()    {    }   
void Two::foo1() {
    One t;
    t.foo();
}   
void Two::foo()  {}   
}
```

I create static lib of One and Two using

```
g++ -c One.cpp; ar cr libOne.a One.o; ranlib libOne.a
g++ -c Two.cpp; ar cr libTwo.a One.o; ranlib libTwo.a
```

For main, I invoke respective `foo1` functions of both the classes and compile the main as follows

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -L. -lOne -lTwo
```

The code compiles even if I change the order of One and Two.

I was expecting the code should not compile unless I repeat the order of One and Two since there is a cyclic dependency.

What could be the reason?

I am running ubuntu 14.04 with g++ version 4.8.2

Answer (score 0):

> I was expecting the code should not compile

First, your code should *compile*, but may fail to *link*. These are different.

Second, you didn't show the contents of `main.cpp`. If it references any method of `class One`, then your code *should* link fine.

To understand why, read [this](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking) or [this](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html).